# Open a direct file on the hard drive from Firefox (file:///)

Tags: firefox, security, html, web-application

I have a small PHP system I created for myself. This system contains a few `.doc` and `.docx` file documents. I want to be able to open them directly from the browser without downloading them.

I created a link: `<a href="file:///c:/mysite/myfile.docx">myfile</a>`. But Firefox does not open the link. `href="http://localhost/myfile.docx"` works fine - it offers me to download the file.

Any ideas on how I can do it? Do I need to change something in the Firefox options or security settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both Firefox and IE8 support the [File URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

> Here are some examples valid for
>   Windows systems, referring to the same
>   file c:\WINDOWS\clock.avi
>
> > file://localhost/c|/WINDOWS/clock.avi
> >     file:///c|/WINDOWS/clock.avi
> >     file://localhost/c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
> >     file:///c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
>
> While the last is the most obvious and
>   human-readable, the first one is the
>   most complete and correct one.

Apparently (from the same url):

> Mozilla browsers refuse to follow file URLs on a page that it has fetched with the HTTP protocol.

but:

> Mozilla browsers can be configured to override this security restriction as detailed in Mozillazine's "[Links to Local Pages Don't Work](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Issues_:_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work)".

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Although the file:/// URI schema did not worked in IE8 and Firefox, i used the extension in the link you gave and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although the solution indicated in [Links to Local Pages Don't Work](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Issues_:_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don't_Work) was buggy for a while, it has been [fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=995943#c158).

For instance if the page with `file://...` links is served on localhost on port 49154, one solution is to

- exit firefox
- edit `prefs.js`, adding the lines

  `user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "localfilelinks");`
  `user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites", "https://localhost:49154");`
  `user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled", "allAccess");`

  and possibly for `https` protocol:

  `user_pref("capability.policy.trustable.sites", "https://localhost:49154");`
- restart firefox

File links should now be opened upon left click

(tested with firefox 45 under kde, for a personal weblog called [elog](https://midas.psi.ch/elog/))